# how to load all JavaScript and css files to WordPress function.php without retyping

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I am moving my HTML5 template to be a wordpress theme. i have a many css and javascript files that i would like to aoutoload without having to type all of the in the functions.php file like this;

```
    function jpen_enqueue_assets() {
      wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css' );

      wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js' , array( 'jquery' ) , false , true );

   }
```

can that be done?  if yes, how can I do it? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make an array of keys with the scripts and styles you want to enqueue and loop over them.

Maybe something like this?

```
$scripts = array(
    'style' => 'responsive',
    'script' => 'bootstrap'
);

foreach($scripts as $key => $script){

    if($key == 'style')
        wp_enqueue_style($script , get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/'.$script.'.css' );

    if($key == 'script')
        wp_enqueue_script($script , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/'.$script.'.js' , array( 'jquery' ) , false , true );

}
```